# ターミナルの出力結果に対して文字列検索を行うには

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

ターミナルでコマンドを実行した際に出力される結果に対して、文字列検索をして結果を絞りたい場合はどうしたら良いでしょうか？

現在はVScodeに出力結果を貼り付けて検索しています。

`defaults domains`と実行すると文字列がたくさん出てくるのでgoogleの文字列を含む値のみ抽出したいです。

**例：出力結果**

```
Apple, google, MS, daison, cola, google...
```

**期待する結果**

```
google, google
```

Comment: 「期待する結果」だけ見れば `echo 'Apple, google, MS, daison, cola, google...' | grep -Po -e 'google,?' | xargs` でよろしいかと思いますが、「"google" という文字列がどの行に含まれていたのか」という情報が抜け落ちる事になります。

Comment: `xargs`だけでは動作しないと思うのですが`grep`で繋げるという意味でしょうか？

Comment: `... | grep -Po -e 'google,?' | xargs` という意味です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` (パイプ) で出力結果をリダイレクトして `grep` コマンドを使うのがオーソドックスな方法の一つかと思います。

```
$ COMMAND | grep 'pattern'
```

"pattern" の部分には正規表現を利用できます。パターンを含む **行** を出力するので、オプションを使えばパターンに一致した箇所に色付けしたりすることもできます。

```
$ COMMAND | grep --color 'pattern'
```

Comment: colorを付けるとパターン部分に色が付きました。ありがとうございます。しかし、colorを使用しない場合は全ての値が表示されてしまうのですが、出来れば非表示に出来ないのでしょうか？`google`という文字列を使用したのですが、出力結果が一つの大きい文字列になってるから非表示は難しいのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の "結果を絞りたい" が何を指しているのかいまいち読み取れないので、元となる出力結果と期待する絞り込み結果？を質問中に含めると良いかもしれません。

Comment: すいません。伝わりにくく更新しました。